# SpringBoot having different root context-path for mvc and static files

Tags: spring-boot, static, resources, contextpath

If I set the `server.servlet.context-path=/something` is there a way to avoid the static files (from the /resources/static folder) to be served on /something and only serve the @Controller on /something?